# gpxpy: Get extension value from gpx file

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, gpx

I’m trying to get the ID from a waypoint in my gpx-file. The ID is placed in the extension tag of my file. I’m using gpxpy to get other values like the latitude and longitude from the file, but I didn’t find a way to get the ID.

Here you can see my code:

```
import gpxpy
node_id = []
gpx_file = open("test.gpx", mode='rt', encoding='utf-8')
gpx = gpxpy.parse(gpx_file)
for waypoint in gpx.waypoints:
    node_id.append(waypoint.extensions.id)
```

And a part of my test.gpx-file:

```
<wpt lat="53.865650" lon="10.684415">
  <extensions>
    <ogr:id>17</ogr:id>
    <ogr:longitude>10.684415</ogr:longitude>
    <ogr:latitude>53.865650</ogr:latitude>
  </extensions>
</wpt>
```

Is there a way to get the id of the waypoint with gpxpy?

Comment: you can read the gpx file and manipulate it. You may find this package useful: https://github.com/nidhaloff/gpx_converter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

waypoint.extensions is just an array. So you can't just get an item by name. You have to iterate through that array. The "name" of the extensions is stored in the "tag" property of the Element, the value in the "text" property. As i don't have your xml-scheme to test with the extension ogr:id, i tried with the following gpx file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" version="1.1" creator="OSMTracker for Android™ - https://github.com/labexp/osmtracker-android" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd ">
    <wpt lat="10.31345465" lon="10.21237815">
        <extensions>
            <id>17</id>
        </extensions>
        <ele>110.0</ele>
        <time>2018-09-29T09:31:58Z</time>
        <name><![CDATA[train station]]></name>
        <sat>0</sat>
    </wpt>
</gpx>
```

I wrote an short function to get the id. It is not tested against anything (for example the extensions doesn't exist).

```
import gpxpy

def getId(waypoint):
    for extension in waypoint.extensions:
        if extension.tag == 'id':
            return extension.text

node_id = []
gpx_file = open("test2.gpx", mode='rt', encoding='utf-8')
gpx = gpxpy.parse(gpx_file)
for waypoint in gpx.waypoints:
    print(getId(waypoint))
```

The functions gets an GPX Waypoint as argument and loops through the extensions array. If that array contains an element with the tag (name) "id" it returns the text (value).

Best regards
Thimo